# Dimension reduction of a 2D-Image via PCA

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dimensionality-reduction

I want to reduce the dimensions of 2D-Images. I have image patches of size `100x50` and I want to reduce the dimension of these patches.

Do I need to first convert the patch`(100x50)` into a vector`(5000x1)` and then apply PCA to reduce the dimension or can I directly apply PCA for dimension reduction on the patch`(100x50)` and reduce the dimension to let's say `2x50`?

Comment: As it was written initially it was not clear whether you want to resize your image or apply PCA from the title. I adjusted the title to reflect the question in the question text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly apply a 2D-PCA. At least it exists and should perform better (reduction-wise) than the 1D-PCA.

A very highly cited research paper from 2004 on this:
Yang, J. et al., 2004. Two-Dimensional PCA: A New Approach to Appearance-Based Face Representation and Recognition. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 26(1), pp.131–137.
[Source](http://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tp/2004/01/i0131-abs.html)

Unfortunately I do not know of a Matlab implementation.

Comment: I did this implementation
`noofdim=4
[r,c] = size(img);       
 %Calculate cov matrix and the PCA matrixes
m = mean(img')';
 S = ((img - m*ones(1,c)) * (img - m*ones(1,c))');     
[Coeff latent]= eig(S);
[latent, ind] = sort(diag(latent), 'descend');
M1 = Coeff(:,ind(1:noofdim));
latent1 = latent(1:noofdim);`

Comment: @FrqKhan Sorry, I have not enough time now to check.

Answer (score 1):

Dimension reduction is `R^n -> R^m` where `n>m` so based on your text I get the impression you mean this instead:

1. resolution resizing

   - changing target resolution
2. data reduction

   - eliminating insignificant data

For image resizing or data reduction there are many ways to do it like:

1. linear/bilinear/cubic/... filtering

   - are suited for visual data resizing (not for data reduction)
2. frequency domain DFFT/DCT/DST based data reduction

   - can be used to changing resolution without significant data loss
   - by converting to frequency domain
   - (optional) removing noise or insignificant data (like JPEG compresion)
   - converting back to spatial domain in desired resolution
   - also can be used to data reduction when you stay on frequency domain
   - and use just significant frequencies (high amplitudes ..)
3. PCA

   - can not be used for predetermined target resolution because
   - it extracts significant data which size is dependent on the content

So the answer really depends on what exactly you need to achieve and for what purpose

Answer (score 0):

PCA takes as input a point in a vector space and projects it onto a subspace. Expressed this way, then it is easy to remember that you need to resize your patch to a vector.

Using Matlab, calling your patch `X`, you can do this easily by calling `X(:)`, you don't have to mess with `reshape`.